# Why does TypeScript refinement work differently when declaring type as union vs optional?

Tags: typescript, types, scope, refinement-type

```
type Dialog1 = { id?: string };

type VisibleDialog = { id: string };
type DestroyedDialog = {};
type Dialog2 = VisibleDialog | DestroyedDialog;

function remove1(dialog: Dialog1) {
  if (!dialog.id) {
    return;
  } 
  //(1)
  document.getElementById(dialog.id); //dialog:Dislog1
  setTimeout(() => {
    //Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not
    //assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
    document.getElementById(dialog.id);
  });
}

function remove2(dialog: Dialog2) {
  if (!("id" in dialog)) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById(dialog.id); //dialog:VisibleDialog
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById(dialog.id); //dialog:VisibleDialog
  });
}
```

The above two functions(`remove1` and `remove2`) have exactly the same meaning from a human point of view while being treated differently by typescript. This does not make sense to me, here is how I reason it about

For `remove1` after (1), ts know `id` is sure to exist, so `document.getElementById(dialog.id)` is OK because it is in the same event loop, but the refinement does not carry out to a new scope(`setTimeout`). Such behavior makes sense to me, `dialog.id` is still subject to change after the check due to the event loop

However, for `remove2`, there is no ts error because the refined type (Dislog2-> dialog:VisibleDialog) is carried out to the `setTimeout`. Such behavior is literally wrong, i.e. run time error

Actually, I can not confidently understand how typescript think about the code, could anyone walk it through or point some related material to me, especially about typescript's refinement and scope.